# Folders creation from Excel list

Tags: vba, excel

I have addresses in excel sheet B2-B40. Numbers in C2-C40. And both these columns colored with red and green color, in different rows.

What I am trying to accomplish is:

1. To create Master folders with different numbers (Column C). Each Master folder with different unique number 2, 3, 5, 8, etc.
2. Inside each master folder, two different folders, Red & Green. i.e. Inside 2 two separate folders, Red & Green.
3. Inside Numbered master folder, then red (or green) folder, the folder of that address (Which falls under it). Example B2, Address is 124 X lane and its corresponding number in C2 column is 9. Both B2 & C2 are in red color.

So the folder shall be created as:
"9" Inside that "Red" inside that "124 x lane".

So the loop shall read all the addresses and create the master folders, inside those two color folders and inside that all the corresponding addresses to color and number.

What I did was (VBSCRIPT)

```
ub Make_Directory()
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim Path As String
Path = "C:\"
MkDir Path & "test"
Path = "C:\test\"
'The next line is your list of names
Set MyRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B40")
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In MyRange
MkDir Path & c.Value
Next
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

What it did is it created all the folders with addresses but all inside test folder. But I am not able to modify it as per my needs.

Help Please.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Excel sheet I created]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add/change to something like this.  You didn't look at column C at all for value, so a loop using row/column reference might make more sense.

```
Sub Make_Directory()

Dim Path As String
Path = "C:\test"
MkDir Path
Path = Path & "\"

On Error Resume Next

For c = 2 to 40
    MkDir Path & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 3).Value
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c,2).Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0) Then
        MkDir Path & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 3).Value & "\Red"
        MkDir Path & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 3).Value & "\Red\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 2).Value
    Else
        MkDir Path & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 3).Value & "\Green"
        MkDir Path & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 3).Value & "\Green\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 2).Value
    End If
Next c
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. While I am trying to run this code it is showing a window to Type a "Macro name". While I ran my earlier code there was no such window. Why is this happening?

Comment: I added your sub name back, so depending on what you copied and pasted in, that could cause that error.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo and left your Each in there.  Updated.

Comment: That's right...MkDir has to have the before path.  Updated again.

Comment: Great. It made the folders, but not inside the test folder. But outside them.

Comment: Sir, what is the meaning of this line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83789/discussion-between-liss-and-neo).

Comment: Sorry, I can't chat at work, but using Cells instead is basically giving a row, column reference.  Cells(c,3) is the cell located at row c, column 3.  If c = 2, then it's the cell at row 2, column 3, so C3 since C is column 3.